# Access only once to a csv file with header using pd.read_csv() in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have to deal with csv file on a distant server, so it takes a very long time.

My csv file is such that the 8 first rows contains a kind of header formatted like `key : value`. Then, at the ninth line comes the columns index formatted as a usual csv file.

Since it is long to access the file, I want to open it only once, but I don't know how to it. 
Indeed, from what I understood pd.read_csv() only takes a file as input, not only its content. 
So this is where I am for the moment :

```
import pandas as pd

with open(r'myFile.csv', "r", encoding = "utf-8") as file:

    header = file.readlines()[:8]

    metaData = [value.split(':') for value in header]
    metaData = {value[0].strip() : value[1].strip() for value in metaData}

    data = pd.read_csv(file, sep=';', header = 8)
```

And the associated error message :

```
EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

Edit with a sample input csv file :

```
key1:value1
key2:value2
key3:value3
key4:value4
key5:value5
key6:value6
key7:value7
key8:value8
column1;column2;column3
values;values;values
values;values;values
values;values;values
values;values;values
```

Comment: Only idea - do you try `header = 9` ?

Comment: Is possible create some data sample, the best file with 10 rows?

Comment: Hmmm, problem is in file, for me your data sample working perfectly. `data = pd.read_csv(file, sep=';', header = 8)`

Comment: Are your data confidental?

Comment: Yes, but doing that, I cannot access the 8 first lines

Comment: @BillBell - I test it again and same error

Comment: @jezrael: Thanks for responding. I withdrew my comment. Pandas has been giving me trouble since I upgraded. It must be some form of configuration error.

Comment: @Maxime: How did you become aware that `read_csv` opens the remote csv twice? Or did you know that already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, your code reads the entire file when you retrieve the header. After that, the file pointer is at the end of the file, so pandas won't get anything more from the file. The trick is to only read the first 8 lines when you want the header, and then pass the partially-read file pointer to pd.read_csv, which will read the rest of it. Here's a simple change to your code to do that:

import pandas as pd

```
with open(r'myFile.csv', "r", encoding = "utf-8") as file:

    header = [file.readline() for x in range(8)]

    metaData = [value.split(':') for value in header]
    metaData = {value[0].strip() : value[1].strip() for value in metaData}

    data = pd.read_csv(file, sep=';')
```

Comment: You're welcome. Just noticed your middle two lines could be replaced by this: `metaData = dict((v.strip() for v in val.split(":")) for val in header)`. Not sure if that counts as a simplification though!

Answer (score 1):

You can create nested `list` and create `DataFrame` by constructor:

```
with open(r'myFile.csv', "r", encoding = "utf-8") as file:

    #get iterators for all lines
    data = file.readlines()

    #filter first 8 for metadata 
    metaData = [value.split(':') for value in data[:8]]
    metaData = {value[0].strip() : value[1].strip() for value in metaData}

    #read lines from 8+ lines
    datas = [value.strip().split(';') for value in data[8:]]
    print (datas)
    [['column1', 'column2', 'column3'], 
     ['values', 'values', 'values'],
     ['values', 'values', 'values'], 
     ['values', 'values', 'values'], 
     ['values', 'values', 'values']]

    df = pd.DataFrame(datas[1:], columns=datas[0])
    print (df)
      column1 column2 column3
    0  values  values  values
    1  values  values  values
    2  values  values  values
    3  values  values  values
```

Comment: to be clear, file objects are iterators. once you do `file.readlines()` the iterator becomes empty and you can't really do anything with it after that. So if you're going to `readlines()` you need to capture all of the output.

Comment: Yes, I change it in code by `data = file.readlines()` instead `header = file.readlines()[:8]
`

Answer (score 0):

I **must** be missing something in the question. Could you not use the following?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('maxime.csv', sep=';', skiprows=7, header=1)
print (df)
```

Result is:

```
  column1 column2 column3
0  values  values  values
1  values  values  values
2  values  values  values
3  values  values  values
```

Comment: or `df = pd.read_csv('maxime.csv', sep=';', header=8)`. But OP need open file only once, your solution open file twice.

Comment: Ah! Obviously I was unaware of that behaviour of this method.

Answer (score 0):

Another method I just found because I needed to check columns existence on line 9 :

```
import pandas as pd

with open(r'myFile.csv', "r", encoding = "utf-8") as file:

    init = file.tell()
    header = file.readlines()[:9]
    file.seek(init)

    metaData = [value.split(':') for value in header]
    metaData = {value[0].strip() : value[1].strip() for value in metaData}

    data = pd.read_csv(file, sep=';', header = 8)
```